# How to update SALESFORCE database using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, salesforce, dbamp

I am trying to update the table in Salesforce SQL server database using Entity Framework by calling a stored procedure but i am getting the below error

"The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "DBAmp.DBAmp" for linked server "SALESFORCE" does not support the required transaction interface."

Though i am able to get the values from the view created in SALESFORCE db

Comment: does salesforce not have API documentation on how to update and or consume their library's ?

Comment: It works with ADO.net methods of updating the database but is throwing error with Entity framework

Comment: To the "very detailed" question I only can google for your error: [DBAmp Error: does not support the required transaction interface
](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009CQuIAM).